# Get specific word from a string if it has no spaces

Tags: python

I am having these strings:

```
552D3AE5|HellothisIsATest__**wordIWant**|someotherstuff|0
3685248S|HellomynameIsAlex__**wordIWant2**|someotherstuff|0
8963252A|HelloiAm25YearsOld__**wordIWant3**|someotherstuff|0
```

Basically what i want is to "extract" from this strings the **wordIWant**

Unfortunately all these are without spaces so i can't use split.
I tried to use `startswith()` but it works only if it's in the begging.

All the strings are having the same template

```
.....|Hello........|.....
```

Comment: Did you try regular expressions?

Comment: Is the format of the string always the same? If you know the string, why do you want to extract it?

Comment: You can also split by char. `'552D3AE5|HellothisIsATest__wordIWant|someotherstuff|'.split('|')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is always in that format, and assuming each line is a different string, you can use:

```
import re

strings = [
    "552D3AE5|HellothisIsATest__wordIWant|someotherstuff|0", 
    "3685248S|HellomynameIsAlex__wordIWant2|someotherstuff|0",
    "8963252A|HelloiAm25YearsOld__wordIWant3|someotherstuff|0"
]

for st in strings:
    word_i_want = re.match(r'__([^|]*)', st).group(1)
```

This would search each string for two underscores, and then everything until it finds a vertical bar. `group(0)` would be the whole match, including the underscores, whereas `group(1)` is just the `wordIWant`, since we enclosed that in brackets.

EDIT:
If your string is just one big chunk, you can instead use this:

```
import re
big_string = 
"""552D3AE5|HellothisIsATest__wordIWant|someotherstuff|0
3685248S|HellomynameIsAlex__wordIWant2|someotherstuff|0
8963252A|HelloiAm25YearsOld__wordIWant3|someotherstuff|0"""

words_i_want = re.findall(r'__([^|]*)', big_string)
```

In this case, `words_i_want` would be a list of the words you want.

Comment: Thank you.Your second answer helped me :)

Answer (score 2):

Split by pipes, then grab the 2nd entry of each string, split by double underscore and take the latter entry and you're done:

```py
data = """
552D3AE5|HellothisIsATest__**wordIWant**|someotherstuff|0
3685248S|HellomynameIsAlex__**wordIWant2**|someotherstuff|0
8963252A|HelloiAm25YearsOld__**wordIWant3**|someotherstuff|0
""".strip().splitlines()

for line in data:
    chunks = line.split("|")
    bits = chunks[1].split('__')
    print(line, bits[1])
```

outputs

```
552D3AE5|HellothisIsATest__**wordIWant**|someotherstuff|0 **wordIWant**
3685248S|HellomynameIsAlex__**wordIWant2**|someotherstuff|0 **wordIWant2**
8963252A|HelloiAm25YearsOld__**wordIWant3**|someotherstuff|0 **wordIWant3**
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do a regex search on `(?<![A-Za-z0-9])wordIWant\w*`, using `\w*` on the right hand side to allow for a possibly longer word:

```
inp = "8963252A|HelloiAm25YearsOld__wordIWant3|someotherstuff|0"
matches = re.findall(r'(?<![A-Za-z0-9])wordIWant\w*', inp)
print(matches)

['wordIWant3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex can do it for you.

```
import re
strings = ["552D3AE5|HellothisIsATest__wordIWant|someotherstuff|0" ,"3685248S|HellomynameIsAlex__wordIWant2|someotherstuff|0", "8963252A|HelloiAm25YearsOld__wordIWant3|someotherstuff|0"]

for string in strings:
    print(re.findall("_\w+", string))
```

It provides a very nice and clean solution here. You just need to remove the _ afterward yourself.

Comment: `re.findall(r"__(\w+)", string)` will be more precise. With only `_\w+`, the string will return each `__wordIWant` instead of just `wordIWant`, since you didn't add a capture group to `\w+`, and since `\w` matches underscores, you also want to include the second underscore distinctly from `\w+`

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a text, like this:

```
text = "8963252A|HelloiAm25YearsOld__wordIWant|someotherstuff|0\n3685248S|HellomynameIsAlex__**wordIWant2**|someotherstuff|0\n8963252A|HelloiAm25YearsOld__**wordIWant3**|someotherstuff|0"
```

this code is for you:

```
word = "wordIWant"
regex = r'%s\w*'%  word
re.findall(regex, text)
# output: ['wordIWant', 'wordIWant2', 'wordIWant3']
```

If instead your input is composed of an array of strings like this:

```
strings = [
    "552D3AE5|HellothisIsATest__wordIWant|someotherstuff|0", 
    "3685248S|HellomynameIsAlex__wordIWant2|someotherstuff|0",
    "8963252A|HelloiAm25YearsOld__wordIWant3|someotherstuff|0"
]
```

You can do this:

```
sum([re.findall(regex, s) for s in strings], [])
# output: ['wordIWant', 'wordIWant2', 'wordIWant3']
```